# How to set opengraph metadata tags for a sphinx document?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm looking to add meta tags to my sphinx document for the [opengraph properties](https://ogp.me/).

I see that sphinx has this meta [directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#html-metadata)

```
.. meta::
   :description: The Sphinx documentation builder
   :keywords: Sphinx, documentation, builder
```

But how do I use it to tags with the property attribute like `<meta property="og:title" content="<title>" />` -- I only see examples with the name attribute?

I see that there's also the [sphinxext-opengraph](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxext-opengraph/) extension, but it looks like that uses `conf.py` to specify the tags, and I want to manually set the tags for each RST document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aforementioned `sphinxext-opengraph` extension currently has a [PR](https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph/pull/50) for setting the values per page. The PR is effectivley done so a new version should be released very soon.

Edit: The PR has been [merged](https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph/releases/tag/v0.6.0). You can now set any tag by adding field lists to the top of the page like so:

```
:og:description: New description

Page Title
==========
```

For more info refer to the [docs](https://sphinxext-opengraph.readthedocs.io/) or the `readme` in the [repo](https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph).

Edit 2: Currently relative image/video/audio file paths are broken on ***purpose***, this will be fixed with [#53](https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph/issues/53)